# Summing columns in a Panda's dataframe where each cell value is a list

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have a single column Dataframe similar to the example below:

```py
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Column': [[10, 100],[20, 200],[30, 300]]})

     Column
0 [10, 100]
1 [20, 200]
2 [30, 300]
```

How can I add the rows element by element such that the result will be:

```py
     Column
0 [60, 600]
```

Comment: Do the list has all the same size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all the arrays have the same size as in the sample data:

```
np.array(df['Column'].to_list()).sum(axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([ 60, 600])
```

Comment: Can `np.sum(..., 0)` directly :p

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the apply function. Try it this way:

```
Import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column': [[10, 100],[20, 200],[30, 300]]})
nums = df.Column.apply(pd.Series)
nums.sum()
```